# Silverlight3: Play files from a .m3u playlist

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, audio

Hy,

does anyone already figured out a way to play .m3u files with Silverlight?

I didn't find a way to do so, and I don't think that it's natively supported by SL.
Any ideas how to manage the playback?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: EDIT: An example would be http://static.radiogong.de/live/low_q.m3u

Comment: Your example playlist only contains another URL to the same playlist...

Answer (score 5):

A m3u playlist is just a text file, with a very simple format (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3u) for details). So yo can just parse it to retrieve the path to the audio files, then read the files normally.

Comment: Okay, than my problem isn't the m3u file, it is the redirect that's within the file. I'm gonna have a look at it.